# Given an index, find that index in a different div list

Tags: jquery, dom, onclick

I have a div with a few dots that are clickable. I have a var that stores the index of the clicked dot. I would like to find the li with that same index on a list that is inside a different div and give it a class "selected", but I'm doing something wrong in this line:

```
 $(this).parent().parent().siblings( $("a.product_img_link") ).find( $("ul.thumbnails-custom-list") ).find( $("li").index( dotIndex ) ).addClass("selected");
```

This is the HTML structure:

```
<a class="product_img_link" href="X">
    <ul class="thumbnails-custom-list">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</a>
<div class="list-inline-controls">
    <div class="list-left-control"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> </div>
    <div class="list-right-control"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> </div>
</div>
<div class="dot-navigation-wrap">
    <div class="dot-navigation-inner-wrap"></div>
</div>
```

And the complete click on dot function:

```
$(".dot-navigation").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
    var dotIndex = $(this).index();
    $(this).parent().parent().siblings($("a.product_img_link")).find($("ul.thumbnails-custom-list")).find($("li").index(dotIndex)).addClass("selected");
})
```

Comment: Where is `.dot-navigation` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method instead of `.index()`

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

```
$(this).parent().parent().siblings("a.product_img_link").find("ul.thumbnails-custom-list li").eq(dotIndex).addClass("selected");
```